# Simulate a href click - Download File

Tags: javascript

I have a "a href" modified from Jquery, I need to run that "href" to download the file, but the event () click does not work.

```
 // window.location = 'data:'+part.mimeType+';base64,'+resp.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'); ---> i cant modify file name
              descarga = $("#links");


               var link = 'data:' + part.mimeType + ';base64,' + resp.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
              // inline.append('<a href="' + link + '" style="display: block" download="'+part.filename+'">' + part.filename + '</a>');

              descarga.attr("href", link);
              descarga.text('text here');
              descarga.attr("download", part.filename);
              document.location.href = link;
              descarga.click();
```

I can not do "windows.location" because it is unpredictable that the file has a certain name and as found in the internet do it in "windows.location" is impossible

Comment: You can't, it's a security violation. Imagine if you visited some random web page and suddenly files began downloading to your computer without your permission.

Comment: oh :( that so bad, i can set name file in windows.location? window.location = 'data:'+part.mimeType+';base64,'+resp.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');

Comment: i can, i can autodownloading ,    var links = document.createElement('a');
                  document.body.appendChild(links); 
                  links.download = part.filename;
                  links.href = link;
                  links.click();
                  document.body.removeChild(link);

Answer (score 2):

i find the solution: =)

```
   var links = document.createElement('a');
                  document.body.appendChild(links); 
                  links.download = part.filename;
                  links.href = link;
                  links.click();
                  document.body.removeChild(link);
```