# How to download the HTML content of a component on click button with angular?

Tags: angular

I have a dialog box where the user input information. At the bottom of the dialog I have a button "Generate" that should generate and download a HTML report using the data entered by the user.

I would like to download the content of the report directly without redirecting the user to a page and then for him to right click on it and "save as..."

I would like to know if there is any way of doing that ?

Angular version: `Angular 13.2.5`

Answer (score 0):

This package works very well and I have used it in an active Angular project.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

You can save the HTML content has a blob and download to the user's computer. Under the hood I am sure it's imitating a click event similar to this: [Simulate a href click - Download File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593879/simulate-a-href-click-download-file).

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

You might need to change the type.

Comment: Hi thanks, for your answer. Any idea how to get the component html for th blob ?

Comment: Can you provide some of your code in your above question.